# Create new screen on startup (Ubuntu Server)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I'm really new to ubuntu server so sorry in advanced if i use wrong terminology etc. 
Basically, i was following a tutorial on how to make a startup service through systemd. I have the script run `screen -S proxy -d -m sh start.sh`. and when I journalctl it, it says that it ran on startup but `screen -ls` shows no screens. I was thinking maybe screens is not loaded when I run the script. How can i fix this?

Comment: In general programs that get started as service by systemd get managed from systemd and not through the intermediate layer of a screen session. Output then gets logged either to a log file or captured by systemd's journald.

Comment: @HBruijn would the screen not be activated though? It doesnt open up whatsoever unless I run the service manually